# AttributeError: module '{path}' has no attribute '{file}'

Tags: python, pycharm

My project looks like this:

```
b4
    \storage
        __init__.py
        b4_common.py
        b4_mysql.py
        b4_storage.py
__init__.py
b4_run.py
```

When I run "python b4_run.py" I get the error:
**AttributeError: module 'b4.storage' has no attribute 'b4_storage'**

I'm not a python expert, especially when it comes to namespace handling, but in Pycharm it sees the pathing just fine and will say that b4.storage.b4_storage.Storage looks OK.
Yes, the Storage class is defined inside b4_storage.py

I had some circular reference errors so I have everything just straight importing rather than "from {file} import {class}".  But when I got passed that I ran into this one, and I don't understand what the problem is.

Some history: I'm trying to convert a Python 2.7 project to 3.12.  I learned a bunch along the way, but got stuck here.  I have no red errors and no solid yellow warnings.

It happens on the second line shown here in b4_common:

```
import b4.storage.b4_storage


class DatabaseStorage(b4.storage.b4_storage.Storage):
```

If I hover over Storage PyCharm understands that Storage is a class defined in b4.storage.b4_storage

I'm mostly bewildered because b4_storage is a file, not an attribute.

Thinking maybe the problem some language issue with handling of "."s and "_"s?  So I renamed the file to b4_dbstorage so there could be no overlap between b4.storage and b4_storage, but that was not the solution.  It only changed the error to "AttributeError: module 'b4.storage' has no attribute 'b4_dbstorage'"

The sub-folders are created as python package rather than plain directories.

I tried merging the contents of b4_storage.py into b4_common.py, but now b4_mysql has the same sort of complaint about b4_common.py.

If it helps, the output looks like it's importing until I try to inherit the Storage object.  Renaming that object (just in case it was a special name now) doesn't change anything .

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 187, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/b4-0.2-py3.10.egg/b4/b4_run.py", line 25, in <module>
    import b4
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/b4-0.2-py3.10.egg/b4/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    import b4.b4_config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/b4-0.2-py3.10.egg/b4/b4_config.py", line 33, in <module>
    import b4.storage.b4_storage
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/b4-0.2-py3.10.egg/b4/storage/b4_storage.py", line 26, in <module>
    import b4.storage.b4_mysql
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/b4-0.2-py3.10.egg/b4/storage/b4_mysql.py", line 26, in <module>
    import b4.storage.b4_common
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/b4-0.2-py3.10.egg/b4/storage/b4_common.py", line 39, in <module>
    class DatabaseStorage(b4.storage.b4_storage.Storage):
AttributeError: module 'b4.storage' has no attribute 'b4_storage'
```

Comment: I created a similar hierarchy on my machine and couldn't reproduce the error. Can you show the contents of `b4\storage\__init__.py`? And is the code *exactly* like you've shown here? Your last error mentions `b4_dbstorage`, not `b4_storage`.

Comment: Packages do not automatically have their modules as attributes. `import` takes a module name, not an expression (one reason that `import` is a statement, not a function), so the fully qualified module name `b4.storage.b4_storage` is not necessarily a valid expression involving the object bound to the name `b4`.

Comment: @BoppreH you can see the whole project at https://github.com/dkman123/B4 (when I'm running it the ini file is configured, so it won't behave the same if you just pull and try to run.

Comment: @chepner I feel like you're on the right track, but I don't understand what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: _It happens on the second line shown here in b4_common_ Instead of pointing out where the error happens, please post the full exact error traceback message.  That way we don't have to guess exactly what the error is or where it happens.

Comment: "I had some circular reference errors so I have everything just straight importing rather than "from {file} import {class}"." - you need to eliminate the circular imports. Changing `from` imports to non-`from` imports isn't a real fix.

Comment: This is exactly the behavior that would result from a circular import situation, where `b4.storage.b4_storage` and `b4.storage.b4_common` are in an import loop and `b4.storage.b4_storage` gets imported first (by some other code). By the time `b4.storage.b4_common` tries to import the other module, `b4.storage.b4_storage` is found in `sys.modules`, so the import succeeds, but the `b4_storage` attribute on `b4.storage` hasn't been bound yet. You **need** to fix your circular dependencies. Changing filenames and import forms will only change the errors, not solve them.

Comment: Thank you @user2357112  I shuffled the objects around so that I could tweak the imports, eliminating the circular reference and I get past that point now.

Answer (score 0):

As @user2357112 pointed out, just changing to import didn't remove the circular reference, so it was still choking pointing back on itself, like an ouroboros.

I was able to move referenced objects, merging from storage to common, but not pulling the whole file in.

That eliminated the import b4_storage within b4_common.  And b4_storage doesn't need to import b4_common anymore, just the main b4 project.

Now I get "Process finished with exit code 120", but I can dig further now.